# Virtualenv: Install python-ldap on gentoo

Tags: python, gentoo

I'm trying to install python-ldap on a Gentoo Server. It is running a Django application which I want to use LDAP Auth. Im using virtualenv to manage my python dependencies. I can't install python-ldap with pip in my virtualenv. It always fails to compile the C parts. I tried to emerge openldap but I alway get "sasl.h no such file or directory". Have anyone managed to get python-ldap working on Gentoo? Im using Python 2.7

Regards,
Philip

Comment: What USE-flags to you use to emerge net-nds/openldap? If you do not need the server, you maybe want to enable the minimal USE-flag. You could also install python-ldap via portage. This will install all deps for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo emerge cyrus-sasl
sudo USE="minimal" emerge openldap
```

Now you can install `python-ldap` package from pip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `dev-libs/cyrus-sasl` too as it provides the needed SASL headers. python-openldap compile fine on my machine. Just for information: my openldap USE flags are: `"berkdb crypt ipv6 kerberos ssl syslog tcpd"`